# RC Snubber Design Hint for 3 phase AC-AC PWM Chopper

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, over-voltage-protection, igbt, snubber

Im trying to design a 3 phase Ac-Ac Pwm Chopper, I'm having difficulty designing the snubber network for the mentioned topology.

Now I tried testing this circuit on bench , with my IGBT snubber values being **10Ω10W** and **0.47uF** Resistance and Capacitance Respectively, Highlighted in red .While my Output RC network Highlighted in Blue had values  **10Ω10W** and  **2.2uF** Resistance and Capacitance Respectively.
This was strictly a hit and trial without any type of short-circuit overload protection circuitry. For trials firstly I ran my circuit on 3 100W lamps. When I ran my circuit , all the freewheeling diode network along with the IGBT's blew off. This had to happen probably because I wasn't thinking clearly and I believe I made a huge mistake of putting 2.2uF caps on the output without any kind of choke in series . How can I optimize my 2 RC networks so that it doesn't blow off at least because of the hardware ,Also For now I have no input Filter on my Circuit.I've Also given the Rated Motor Parameters below for the current Motor I was going to run my Circuit on in future.

```
Circuit Parameters  : 
IGBT : FGA25N120 , 25Amp
Supply Voltage : 220V
Line Frequency : 50Hz 
Switching Freq : 1KHz

Motor Parameters : 
Rated Power      : 4Kw
Line to Line Voltage : 380v
Frequency         : 50Hz 
Stator Resistance  : 1.43Ω
Stator Leakage Inductance : 0.00523H
```

Citation Link : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8675728

[image]